# How can I get list selected items in sencha touch 2.3.1

Tags: sencha-touch

How can I get selected items of Ext.List on sench-touch 2.3.1?
Thank you.

```
[View]
{
  xtype: 'list',
  itemTpl: '{MATERIAL_ID} {TEXT}',
      mode: 'MULTI'
}

[Controller]
'queryresult #queryButton': {
   tap: function(){
      var list = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('queryresult #list')[0];

      //todo: get selected items
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var records = list.getSelection();
```

Check out this documentation page: 
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-method-getSelection

Comment: Thank you for giving me a direction.

Answer (score 2):

Strangely, I use list.getSelection(), return 
    `"TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'list.getSelectiion()')"`

use list.selected.getRange() can get right result.....

But...document say 
    `function getSelection(){ return list.selected.getRange(); }`

Comment: fix a typo. it's not getSelectiion but getSelection